# Android Annotation 3.1 how to inject requestfactory in resttemplate

Tags: android, spring, android-annotations

how can i inject this in RestTemplate android annotations??

```
  String url = "site";
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
  connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
  connection.setUseCaches(true);
  connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see [this](https://github.com/yDelouis/selfoss-android/blob/master/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Ffr%2Fydelouis%2Fselfoss%2Frest%2FSelfossRest.java) and [this](https://github.com/yDelouis/selfoss-android/blob/master/app%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Ffr%2Fydelouis%2Fselfoss%2Frest%2FSelfossApiRequestFactory.java) to have an example of how to use AndroidAnnotations to inject a request factory in `RestTemplate`.
The main steps are :

- Create a class implementing `ClientHttpRequestFactory` or extending `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. This class can be annotated with `@EBean`. In the method `prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod)`, you can modify the `HttpURLConnection`.
- Create an interface annotated with `@Rest` like explained [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API#rest) and set the class implementing `ClientHttpRequestFactory` you created in the field `requestFactory` of the annotation `@Rest`.

Comment: connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached"); why i am getting server error when i add this to  preprareConnection? @yDelouis